# CMake error, when trying to install Xournalapp

Tags: cmake, mingw

I am following the guides to install Xournal and CMake:

[MIngw terminal where error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlZeQ.png)

```
CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool. 
Make Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after Enablelanguage
Make Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after Enablelanguage
```

The CMake comes from xournalapp so I don't think there is a mistake. I want to know if I made a mistake during install, or if I need to update my `PATH` variable on windows to include the mingw compiler.

Comment: Do you have *ninja* (build system) installed? This is what the error message talking about.

Comment: no I don't have it, what is the possibility for me to install it on Mingw?

Comment: On MinGW you probably have `make` utility (check that by typing `make` in the terminal). So you may use this utility instead of ninja, just pass `-G "Unix Makefiles"` additional option to `cmake`.

Comment: Cmake error: error : generator: Unix makefiles     Does not match the generator used previously: Ninja   Sadly it doesn't work because I still want to use the cmake and not rebuild one

Comment: Remove the build directory and try again. This should eliminate `Does not match the generator used previously` error.

Comment: Worked! thank you, just had to redo everything.